# How can I get the date a video was uploaded through the Youtube API?

Tags: php, api, date, youtube

I'm confused as to where I can find the date a youtube video was uploaded. I've been using the following two functions:

```
$videoEntry->getUpdated()->getText();
$videoEntry->getVideoRecorded()
```

The first is when the video was last updated, and I'm not so sure that is the same as when it was uploaded.
The "video recorded" is not always present. I assume its taken from camera metadata.

I need the date it was uploaded to the youtube website. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was actually hoping for an answer through the PHP API specifically. None of the functions in the documentation were working, though I was able to get the date uploaded from PHP like so:

```
$videoEntry->mediaGroup->uploaded->text
```

Comment: Maybe add 'php' as a tag to this question then, if it's specific to that language

Comment: I tried the code above but it didn't quite work. So I tried $videoEntry->published and that worked.

Answer (score 3):

From the [YouTube API Reference Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_media:description).

"The `<yt:uploaded>` tag specifies the time that a playlist entry was originally uploaded to YouTube."

If you just browse the feed file for a particular video, such as http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/bTL5bErRk-g, you can see the uploaded date in the "published" tag, near the top:

```
<entry>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/bTL5bErRk-g</id>
    <published>2009-08-02T13:59:54.000Z</published>
    <updated>2009-10-29T11:20:11.000Z</updated>
...
```

Whatever 'published' technically means to YouTube, that's my video, and I can confirm that that's when I uploaded it.

Answer (score 2):

For Youtube V3, it's something like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=(youtube_video_id)&key=(your_oauth_key)

"publishedAt" seems to have the date and time of publication in UTC timezone

Answer (score 1):

Latest Youtube API supports date.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples